# Mantaining text-to-speech speaking in fragment when screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, text-to-speech, screen-orientation

I'm converting my activity-based  app to fragments for adapting to tablets.
I have activities with text-to-speech API that continues speaking if the screen rotates due to they are retained in the manifest file.

To do this, I’m splitting my old activities in three classes: a parent activity, an UI fragment and a headless fragment with `setRetainInstance(true)` that is including the text-to-speech function. All of them are linked via interfaces through the activity (I’ve seen that is the correct way to do this). I don’t select “orientation” in the manifest.

But now, my problem is that when screen rotates, the speech turns off. Debugging the process, TTS is speaking during all the recreation process but when the activity resumes, the TTS loses and stops.

I would appreciate your help.

**Activity:**

```
     public class ParentActivity extends Main_Activity implements
            Fragment_ListaCorta.Callbacks, Fragment_UI.Callbacks,
            Fragment_Retain.Callbacks {

        public static final String ORIGEN = ParentActivity .class
                .getSimpleName();

    Fragment_Retain fragmentRetain;
    Fragment_UI fragmentUI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTema(this));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment);

        super.context = this;

        if (findViewById(R.id.framelayout_contenedor_detalle) != null) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentUI = new Fragment_UI();
            fragmentRetain = (Fragment_Retain) fm
                    .findFragmentByTag(Fragment_Retain.NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO);
            if (fragmentRetain == null) {
                fragmentRetain = new Fragment_Retain();
                ft.add(fragmentRetain,
                        Fragment_Retain.NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO);
            }
            ft.replace(R.id.framelayout_contenedor_detalle, fragmentUI,
                    Fragment_UI.NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO);
            ft.commit();

        } else {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentUI= new Fragment_UI();
            fragmentRetain = (Fragment_Retain) fm
                    .findFragmentByTag(Fragment_Retain.NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO);
            if (fragmentRetain == null) {
                fragmentRetain = new Fragment_Retain();
                ft.add(fragmentRetain ,
                        Fragment_Retain.NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO);
            }
            ft.replace(R.id.framelayout_contenedor_detalle1, fragmentUI,
                    Fragment_UI.NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEntradaSelecionada(String id) {
        int idInt = Integer.valueOf(id);
        opcionMenuActiv(idInt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUIBotonPulsado(int posicion) {
        fragmentRetain.onClick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetainCambiaUltimoPlay(String ultimoPlay,
            String utteranceId) {
        fragmentUI.onCambioParrafo(ultimoPlay, utteranceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTtsOk(boolean oK) {
        if (oK) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    fragmentUI.buttonTextToSpeech
                            .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    fragmentUI.buttonTextToSpeech
                            .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**UI fragment**

```
 public class Fragment_UI extends Main_Fragment implements
            OnClickListener {

        public static ImageButton buttonTextToSpeech;
    TextView textView01, textView02, textView03, textView04, textView05,
            textView06, textView07, textView08, textView09, textView10,
            textView11, textView12, textView13, textView14, textView15,
            textView16, textView17, textView18, textView19, textView20,
            textView21;
    String tts01, tts02, tts03, tts04, tts05, tts06, tts07, tts08, tts09,
            tts10, tts11, tts12, tts13, tts14, tts15, tts16, tts17, tts18,
            tts19, tts20, tts21;

    private static final String[] ESTROFA = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
            "18", "19", "20" };

    private int colorDestacado;
    private int colorAnterior;

    (...)
protected int textView21Color;

    public static final String NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO = Fragment_UI.class
            .getSimpleName();
    public static final int PLAY = 1;
    public static final int PAUSE = 2;
    private static int mPosicion = PLAY;
    public boolean ttsOk = false;


    private Callbacks mCallbacks = CallbacksVacios;


    public interface Callbacks {

        public void onUIBotonPulsado(int posicion);
    }


    private static Callbacks CallbacksVacios = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onUIBotonPulsado(int posicion) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Error: La actividad debe implementar el callback del fragmento");
        }
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = CallbacksVacios;
    }


    public Fragment_UI() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,
                container, false);

        TypedArray a = getActivity().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { R.attr.colorTts });
        colorDestacado = getResources().getColor(a.getResourceId(0, 0));
        a.recycle();

        buttonTextToSpeech = (ImageButton) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.buttonTextToSpeech);
        if (Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTTSCheck()) {
            if (Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTTSok()) {
                buttonTextToSpeech.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonTextToSpeech.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        textView01 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView01);
        ...
        textView20 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView20);
        textView21 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);

        tts01 = textView01.getText().toString();
        tts02 = textView02.getText().toString();
        tts03 = textView03.getText().toString();
        tts04 = textView04.getText().toString();
        tts05 = textView05.getText().toString();
        tts06 = textView06.getText().toString();
        tts07 = textView07.getText().toString();
        tts08 = textView08.getText().toString();
        tts09 = textView09.getText().toString();
        tts10 = textView10.getText().toString();
        tts11 = textView11.getText().toString();
        tts12 = textView12.getText().toString();
        tts13 = textView13.getText().toString();
        tts14 = textView14.getText().toString();
        tts15 = textView15.getText().toString();
        tts16 = textView16.getText().toString();
        tts17 = textView17.getText().toString();
        tts18 = textView18.getText().toString();
        tts19 = textView19.getText().toString();
        tts20 = textView20.getText().toString();
        tts21 = textView21.getText().toString();

        if (tts01 == "")
            textView01.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts02 == "")
            textView02.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts03 == "")
            textView03.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts04 == "")
            textView04.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts05 == "")
            textView05.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts06 == "")
            textView06.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts07 == "")
            textView07.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts08 == "")
            textView08.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts09 == "")
            textView09.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts10 == "")
            textView10.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts11 == "")
            textView11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts12 == "")
            textView12.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts13 == "")
            textView13.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts14 == "")
            textView14.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts15 == "")
            textView15.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts16 == "")
            textView16.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts17 == "")
            textView17.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts18 == "")
            textView18.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts19 == "")
            textView19.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts20 == "")
            textView20.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (tts21 == "")
            textView21.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonTextToSpeech:

            mCallbacks.onUIBotonPulsado(R.id.buttonTextToSpeech);
            if (mPosicion == PLAY) {
                buttonTextToSpeech.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
                mPosicion = PAUSE;
            } else {
                buttonTextToSpeech.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                mPosicion = PLAY;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onCambioParrafo(String ultimoPlay, String utteranceId) {
        if (ultimoPlay.equals("")) {
            if (utteranceId.equals(ESTROFA[0])) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        colorAnterior = textView01.getCurrentTextColor();
                        textView01.setTextColor(colorDestacado);
                        textView01Color = textView01.getCurrentTextColor();
                    }
                });
            }//...

            } else if (utteranceId.equals(ESTROFA[21])) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        textView21.setTextColor(colorAnterior);
                        textView21Color = 0;

                        buttonTextToSpeech
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
                        mPosicion = PLAY;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Retained fragment with TTS**

```
    public class Fragment_Retain extends Main_Fragment implements
            TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

        private static String tts01, tts02, tts03, tts04, tts05, tts06, tts07, tts08, tts09,
                tts10, tts11, tts12, tts13, tts14, tts15, tts16, tts17, tts18,
                tts19, tts20, tts21;

    private static String ultimoPlay = "";

    private static final String[] ESTROFA = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",
            "18", "19", "20" };

    public static final String NOMBRE_FRAGMENTO = Fragment_Retain.class
            .getSimpleName();


    private Callbacks mCallbacks = CallbacksVacios;


    public interface Callbacks {

        public void onRetainCambiaUltimoPlay(String ultimoPlay,
                String utteranceId);

        public void onTtsOk(boolean oK);
    }


    private static Callbacks CallbacksVacios = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onRetainCambiaUltimoPlay(String ultimoPlay,
                String utteranceId) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTtsOk(boolean oK) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        Log.i("Retain", "onAttach");

        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Error: La actividad debe implementar el callback del fragmento");
        }
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        mCallbacks = CallbacksVacios;
    }


    public Fragment_Retain() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("Retain", "onCreate");

        setRetainInstance(true);

        // Inicio proceso TTS
        if (!Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTTSNoMostrar()
                && !Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTTSCheck()) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            DialogoAdvertenciaTTS dialogo = new DialogoAdvertenciaTTS();
            dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagPersonalizado");
        }

        // Control proceso TTS
        if (Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTTSCheck()) {
            if (Activity_Principal.preferencias.getTTSok()) {
                tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
                if (tts.isSpeaking()) {
                    buttonTextToSpeech.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
                }
            } else {
                Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
                checkTTSIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
                startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
            }
        }

        tts01 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario01));
        tts02 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario02));
        tts03 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario03));
        tts04 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario04));
        tts05 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario05));
        tts06 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario06));
        tts07 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario07));
        tts08 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario08));
        tts09 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario09));
        tts10 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario10));
        tts11 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario11));
        tts12 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario12));
        tts13 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario13));
        tts14 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario14));
        tts15 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario15));
        tts16 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario16));
        tts17 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario17));
        tts18 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario18));
        tts19 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario19));
        tts20 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario20));
        tts21 = Utiles.depurarTextoTTS(getResources().getString(
                R.string.sagrario21));
    }

    public void onClick() {

        Log.i("Retain", "onClick");
        if (tts.isSpeaking()) {
            ultimoPlay = params.get(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID);
            tts.stop();
        } else {

            if (ultimoPlay.equals("") || ultimoPlay.equals(ESTROFA[0])) {
                speakOut(tts01, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ESTROFA[0]);
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[0]);
            } else if (ultimoPlay.equals(ESTROFA[1])) {
                speakOut(tts02, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ESTROFA[1]);
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[1]);
            } else if (ultimoPlay.equals(ESTROFA[2])) {
                speakOut(tts03, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ESTROFA[2]);
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[2]);
            }....

            ....} else if (ultimoPlay.equals(ESTROFA[20])) {
                speakOut(tts21, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ESTROFA[20]);
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[20]);
            }
            ultimoPlay = "";
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("Retain", "onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
            } else { // missing data, install it Intent
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        Log.i("Retain", "onInit");
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            Locale loc = new Locale(langPagina);
            int result = tts.isLanguageAvailable(loc);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
                tts.setLanguage(loc);
                Activity_Principal.preferencias.setTTSok(true);
                mCallbacks.onTtsOk(true);
                hablarTexto();
            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");

                mCallbacks.onTtsOk(false);
                Activity_Principal.preferencias.setTTSok(false);
                String mensaje = getActivity().getString(
                        R.string.ttsIdiomaNoSoportadoToast);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
            Activity_Principal.preferencias.setTTSok(false);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void hablarTexto() {

        Log.i("Retain", "hablarTexto");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    onDoneSpeaking(utteranceId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Log.d(TAG, "set utternace completed listener");
            tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
                    onDoneSpeaking(utteranceId);
                }

            });
        }
    }

    private void onDoneSpeaking(String utteranceId) {
        Log.i("Retain", "onDoneSpeaking");
        if (ultimoPlay.equals("")) {
            if (utteranceId.equals(ESTROFA[0])) {
                speakOut(tts02, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ESTROFA[1]);
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[1]);

            } else if (utteranceId.equals(ESTROFA[1])) {
                speakOut(tts03, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ESTROFA[2]);
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[2]);

            } //...
            } else if (utteranceId.equals(ESTROFA[20])) {
                mCallbacks.onFragmentRetainCambiaUltimoPlay("", ESTROFA[21]);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void onBackPressed() {
        Log.i("Retain", "onBackPressed");

        if (tts.isSpeaking()) {
            ultimoPlay = params.get(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID);
            tts.stop();

        }

        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("Retain", "onDestroy");
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because of when screen orientation changes activity restart so you have to restrict orientation in manifest

Comment: I need recreate the activity because I have several layouts for it, depending if it's portrait or landscreen. That's the reason because I don't maintain the manifest restriction, I reorganise the code in those blocks and I'm retaining the fragment with TTS.

Comment: If you can't persist the TTS object in an Activity then perhaps you should implement it in a service?